# How to install gcj on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation

I received the following results of `sudo apt-get install gcj` in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcj
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gcj is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcj' has no installation candidate
```

How to install gcj on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I guess the problem is that `gcj` is deprecated and removed from the GCC trunk. You should consider changing the compiler. Check the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java

Answer (score 0):

gcj is provided by gcj-jdk, gcj-4.8-jdk, gcj-4.9-jdk, gcj-5-jdk and   gcc-snapshot in Ubuntu 16.04. Before you try to install any of these packages, run the following command to show what version(s) of gcc you have installed on your system.

```
apt-cache policy gcc gcc-4.8 gcc-4.9 gcc-5
```

If you have only gcc-4.8 installed on your system, it's obvious that you don't need to install gcj-4.9-jdk or gcj-5-jdk.